# "Out of memory" error when using TTask.Run for a large number of job running in parallel

Tags: delphi

I am trying to use the new `Parallel Programming Library` or `System.Threading.pas` in `Delphi`.

I have a large number of jobs to work in parallel using `TTask.Run`.  Here is the code snippet:

```
var D: TDataSet;
    T: ITask;
    TaskList: TList<ITask>;
    Q: TThreadedQueue<TData>;
begin
  Q := TThreadedQueue<TData>.Create;

  D := Create_Uni_Direction_DataSet;
  D.Open;

  TaskList := TList<ITask>.Create;

  while not D.Eof do begin
    Q.PushItem(GetData(D));
    T := TTask.Run(
           procedure begin
           var A: TData;
           begin
             A := Q.PopItem;
             Process(A);
             ...
           end
         );
    D.Next;
    TaskList.Add(T);
  end;

  TTask.WaitForAll(TaskList.ToArray);
  ...

  TaskList.Free;
  Q.Free;
end;
```

Please note that the code has simplified for illustration purpose.

The code will return `Out of Memory` error at runtime in Win32 platform.

The memory issue is obvious due to I attempt to keep a large number of ITask reference in `TaskList`.

There are some reasons why I use `TTask.Run` instead of `TParallel`:

1. I couldn't determine the Low and High bound of tasks. e.g.: uni-directional dataset
2. The threaded task update UI control to report status via `TThread.Synchronize`.  Using `TThread.Synchronize` in `TParallel` will freeze application.

As I want to monitor and make sure these tasks shall execute before it continue on, I use `TTask.WaitForAll` to check items in `TaskList.ToArray`.

Apparently, there should have a number of tasks complete execution while the `for` loop still working.  These completed tasks are no longer needed for to be monitored and thus may remove from `TaskList`.

However, it is not easy to decide or get notified if tasks has complete it's job.  Perhaps there are methods or ready constructs in Delphi's `PPL` that can solve my problem that I am not aware of.  Please share your ideas or solutions.

Comment: WaitForAll is still buggy.

Comment: This can be solved with a data pipeline. It is not covered by PPL for now but you can use the PPL to build your own data pipeline.

Comment: @SirRufo Can you explain more on how "data pipeline" may helps on my problem?  I have no clue at all what the "data pipeline" you mention here.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2010/11/multistage-processes-with.html to get the idea of pipelines. The buffer queues between the stages limit the memory consumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to solve the issue by perform `WaitForAll` on `ITask` items in batch of `100,000`.

First, I define a helper class for `TThreadedQueue<TArray<ITask>>`:

```
type
  TThreadedTasksQueue_Helper = class helper for TThreadedQueue<TArray<ITask>>
  public
    function WaitForAll(const aTasks: TArray<ITask>): IFuture<Integer>;
  end;

function TThreadedTasksQueue_Helper.WaitForAll(const aTasks: TArray<ITask>): IFuture<Integer>;
begin
  PushItem(aTasks);

  Result := TTask.Future<Integer>(
    function: Integer
    var A: TArray<ITask>;
    begin
      A := PopItem;
      TTask.WaitForAll(A);
      Result := Length(A);
    end
  );
end;
```

I then amend lengthy looping to perform `WaitForAll` for ITask in a batch of `100,000`:

```
var i: Integer;
    Q: TThreadedQueue<Integer>;
    Batches: TList<IFuture<Integer>>;
    Batch: IFuture<Integer>;
    WaitForQ: TThreadedQueue<TArray<ITask>>;
    TaskList: TList<ITask>;
begin
  Q := TThreadedQueue<Integer>.Create;
  WaitForQ := TThreadedQueue<TArray<ITask>>.Create;
  Batches := TList<IFuture<Integer>>.Create;
  TaskList := TList<ITask>.Create;

  for i := 1 to 50000000 do begin
    Q.PushItem(i);
    TaskList.Add(
      TTask.Run(
        procedure
        begin
          Q.PopItem;
        end
      )
    );

    if i mod 100000 = 0 then begin
      Batches.Add(WaitForQ.WaitForAll(TaskList.ToArray));
      TaskList.Clear;
    end;
  end;

  Batches.Add(WaitForQ.WaitForAll(TaskList.ToArray));
  TaskList.Clear;

  for Batch in Batches do Batch.Value;

  Q.Free;
  WaitForQ.Free;
  TaskList.Free;
  Batches.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a perfect application for `TParallel.For`:

```
TParallel.For(1, 50000000,
  procedure(i: Int64)
  begin
  end);
```

This way, you let the RTL manage how many threads are active at once, and you don't have to create 50 million objects just to have millions of idle tasks sitting around.

Comment: Lets cross fingers if it is implemented well enough for that case - it should have implemented to do so

Comment: I have simplified the code snippet for illustration purpose.  I have to use `TTask.Run` instead of `TParallel` in my actual application.

Comment: @ChauCheeYang Then it is up to you add this important detail to your question.

Comment: If you've "simplified" the question such that it no longer represents your actual problem, then I don't see what more I can offer. Please explain your real problem.

Comment: @RobKennedy.  I have edited my question by looping a uni-directional dataset that I couldn't determine the range at runtime.  This make `TParallel` not suitable for the case.